# Exemplary 2D game engine

Tags: c++, game-engine

Is anyone here able to point me to a simple and well designed C++ 2D open source game engine? The genre is less important, I wish to learn by example. I wouldn't want anything particularly complex as I'm interested in learning general concepts, rather than getting into the nitty-gritty of the engine implementation.

Comment: For which OS/platform? Windows? Linux/POSIX?

Comment: Should not matter. I'm trying to learn basic concepts.

Answer (score 3):

If I were you I'd look into [ClanLib](http://clanlib.org/wiki/Main_Page) - it is open source, cross platform, and the source packages contain 50 or so easy-to-follow examples, from simple image rendering, to a fully working server-client **dice wars** implementation.

And if you're eager to get started it's easy to set up with Visual Express, so you can play with in in no time.

Also: [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines) are some others if you want to give them a try.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I learned a lot, looking through the source code of [Frogatto](http://www.frogatto.com/), even the source code can be viewed only [here](http://www.frogatto.com/viewvc.cgi/frogatto/trunk/src/).

It is of course a more complex game, but there is much to learn regarding software/game architecture and design.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at SuperTux, it's a nice little platformer game inspired by Mario, written in C++.
There is a builtin level editor, too.